# How to specify for files with double extensions in file explorer such as vcf.gz in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm playing with the file filter object from Electron's api. You create a file filter object like this. filters:

```
[ {name: 'VC Files', extensions: ['vcf', 'gz']}, ]
```

However, I can't successfully specify for the file explorer to accept combination of file extension like vcf.gz. I checked online and the documentation for the [electron API](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/structures/file-filter/) but haven't made any luck in successfully specifying for the file explorer to select for only .vcf.gz file extension such as this filters:

```
[ {name: 'VC Files', extensions: ['vcf.gz']}, ]
```

Has anyone has success in achieving this?